# sup as a colimit

Tags: category-theory, supremum-and-infimum

How does $\text{sup}$ become a (co)limit in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Does it actually become $\text{lim}$ or $\text{colim}$?

I.e. I wish, in the natural order $\leq$ in $\mathbb{R}$, that the thin

subcategory $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$ naturally satisfies $\sup X=\text{(co)lim} X$

to see that $\mathbb{R}$ is (co)complete in the categorical sense.

Comment: It becomes a colimit if you let an arrow $x \to y$ exist if and only if $x \leq y$. If you take the opposite of this category it becomes a limit.

Comment: Defining, for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x\rightarrow y$ when $x\leq y$ you get that for every diagram $F:J\to \mathbb{R}$, its co-limit would be $\sup(F(J))$, if the supremum exits. But taking $J=\mathbb{N}$ and $F$ the inclusion in $\mathbb{R}$, you see that not all diagrams have co-limits. Such a co-limit would be an element $C\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\rightarrow C$ for all $x\in F(J)$. You will need to add an extra object to the category $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$, and define $x\leq +\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ to make it co-complete.

Comment: It is [finitely co-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_category), though.

Comment: As totoro mentioned, $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete (as a category) because $\mathbb{R}$ is not a complete lattice, that is, not every subset admits an infimum/supremum. When we say $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, we are (generally) talking about completeness of metric spaces, that is, every Cauchy sequence converges. Fortunately we can see metric spaces as categories enriched over $([0,\infty],+,0)$, in which case we can formulate the notion of Cauchy completeness in the enriched category setting, which generalizes the classical notion. nLab has an article (Cauchy complete category) on the subject.

Answer (score -2):

Any topological space $X$ can become a category, whose objects are the open sets in $X$, and the morphisms are $$\mathrm{Hom}(U,V) := \begin{cases} V\hookrightarrow U & \text{if } V\subseteq U, \\ \varnothing & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

I'm not sure if you should reverse the inclusions like that. Either way, if $X$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}$, try inducing the order topology on it, and then take the colimit of all of its open subsets. I think you should take $X$ to be closed as well, which isn't a problem since the supremum of $X$ equals that of $\overline{X}$.

Also, you might instead want to define a category whose objects are the *closed* subsets of $X$.

Comment: In your setting, the colimit of the collection of open subsets of $X$ would be the empty set, since it is terminal among open subsets of $X$. If you don't reverse inclusions, then it becomes the interior of $X$. In any case, that's not the correct way to do it; the supremum is not defined by the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ but by the order!